# Websocket connection fails in the browser, but works in Postman

Tags: javascript, java, websocket, jwt, authorization

I am trying to make my backend and frontend communicate trough web sockets using STOMP. It is very weird that I get `401(Unauthorized)` status code when I try to connect from my browser, but `200(OK)` when connecting from by Postman after login. It is important to mention that i keep my `jwt` in the `sessionStorage` on my browser and i build the Authorization Header with it and pass it to the stompClient connection.

Below is the client code in JS:

```js
async function connect() {
    var socket = new SockJS("http://localhost:8080/api/websocket");
    let stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
    const token = sessionStorage.getItem("jwtToken");
    const headers = {
      Authorization: "Bearer " + token,
    };
    const headersAuth = { headers };
    console.log(headersAuth);
    stompClient.connect({ headersAuth }, function (frame) {
      stompClient.subscribe("/topic/events", function (messageOutput) {
        const msg = JSON.parse(messageOutput.body);

        if (msg.id_user === sessionStorage.getItem("jwtToken")) {
          setMess(
            "for the client with id " +
              msg.id_user +
              " the max energy for device with ID " +
              msg.id_device +
              " has been EXCEDEED with " +
              msg.diferenta
          );
          setOpen(true);
        }
        console.log(msg.id_user);
      });
    });
  }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: did u find the solution?